# BundleConfig.cs é necessário mesmo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou lendo alguma coisa sobre MVC, WebAPI e AngularJS. Todos os exemplos que eu peguei, seja do Macoratti ou outros pedem para fazer alguma configuração no BundleConfig.cs. Porém uso VS2017 e ao criar o projeto de testes, na pasta `App_Start` não tenho esse arquivo. Devo criá-lo e inserir as linhas dentro dele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite, amigo.

O BundleConfig.cs é muito importante sim!

Te dá mais possibilidades.

Exemplo:

Centralizar e escolher a ordem de execução de scripts .js e a mesma coisa para seus arquivos de estilo .css...

Digo isso para projetos ASP.NET MVC, num projeto com WebAPI, esse arquivo não fará muito sentido, principalmente se for com AngularJS, que pode substituir tudo que você faria nesse arquivo no próprio projeto AngularJS.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Quando criei o projeto, eu o fiz como MVC e não criou o arquivo. O que faço então?

Comment: @pnet veja: [How do I add BundleConfig.cs to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668280/how-do-i-add-bundleconfig-cs-to-my-project)

Comment: @Marconi, valeu. Consegui criar o arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

O WebAPI não usa `BundleConfig.cs` "diretamente", só pra constar devido a tag que você adicionou [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api), o WebAPI é pra criar serviços com REST, podendo ter o formato Json ou Xml no corpo da resposta e do payload.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre WebAPI, mas voltando ao `BundleConfig.cs`, ele tem sentido ser usado em páginas web, então você não vai usar com WebAPI, ao menos "não diretamente", já que é possível em um mesmo projeto trabalhar WebAPI e outro tipo, como MVC.

Agora falando sobre criar o projeto e o `BundleConfig.cs` estar ausente isto deve ter sido porque você criou um "Web Site" (atalho <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) com Razor v3, este não vem com a pasta `App_Code` ou `App_Start`

Pela tag [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) creio que você queira criar um projeto com asp.net-mvc, então no VS aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> e selecione ASP.NET Web Application (eu uso a versão 4.6.1):

> [image: ASP.NET Web Application]

Depois selecione MVC (note que se você desejar criar um projeto `MVC`+`Webp API` selecione aonde esta escrito *Add folders and core references for:* e selecione a opção `Web API`):

> [image: mvc]

Depois de criar note que aparece a pasta `App_Start`

> [image: Pasta App_Start]

Comment: Eu criei um projeto MVC. Antes eu havia criado um MVC e WEBAPI, mas desisti deste por enquanto e criei outro apenas MVC. Isso é um teste, em que o cara quer um projeto MVC com Web API e Angular e Ado.Net e Entity.

Comment: Criei o projeto MVC mas Empty e não com o template MVC. Não sei se foi isso, mas eu já criei o BundleConfig no meu projeto, seguindo o link do colega Marconi.

Comment: @pnet mas aquilo é criar manualmente, se o projeto é novo e não tem nada ou esta aprendendo faça como eu disse.

Answer (score 0):

`BundleConfig` ou `bundling` nao é so uma questao de organizacao, e sim de performace

Agora numa webapi nao faz sentido nenhum usar ao menos que vc tenha feito algumas paginas web ou uma documentacao(mais de uma pagina) que precisa de css/js

**Edicao:**
MVC ou nao, quando voce tem um paginas webs(View) e faz o uso do content(js/css) é recomendado usar o bundling(BundleConfig) para otimizar o first-load e organizar o seu content.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

voce pode ler mais na ["Documentacao"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: Eu sei que web API não faz sentido, mas a pergunta está para MVC. Coloquei a tag Web API devido ao fato que usarei também, mas não um projeto apenas web API, mas junto com MVC.

Comment: MVC ou nao, quando voce tem um paginas webs(View) e faz o uso do content(js/css) é recomendado usar o bundling(BundleConfig) para otimizar o first-load e organizar o seu content

Comment: entao MVC - V de view, sim é recomendado vc usar o bundling para melhorar a perfomace do first-load e organizar o seu codigo

Comment: Valeu cara, já adicionei o BundleConfig em meu projeto. Não sei porque o VS2017 não criou se eu criei um projeto MVC apenas. Vou sim usar REST no projeto com Web API, é uma obrigatoriedade do teste, vou usar para as consultas. Usarei Ado.Net para persistir e Entity para fazer get no banco e trazer as consultas, já que eles querem Ado.Net e Entity obrigatoriamente.

Comment: uma recomendacao a parte, leia um pouco sobre arquitetura em camadas.

Comment: Valeu, isso é o que eu tenho feito. É que às vezes surge dúvidas e corro pra cá.